# VMs won't run on VirtualBox (Guru Meditation error 79)

Tags: nvidia, virtualbox, intel, 19.04

None of my virtual machines (Windows and Linux guests) won't run on my PC (Kubuntu 19.04, Core i5-6500, 16GB, NVIDIA 430).  I tried installing VirtualBox from Ubuntu's repo and Oracle's repo.

They do run, however, on my laptop with 8GB RAM and Core i7-4700MQ.

```
00:00:01.377634 Changing the VM state from 'POWERING_ON' to 'RUNNING'
00:00:01.377645 Console: Machine state changed to 'Running'
00:00:01.380161 Changing the VM state from 'RUNNING' to 'GURU_MEDITATION'
00:00:01.380178 Console: Machine state changed to 'GuruMeditation'
00:00:01.381957 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
00:00:01.381958 !!
00:00:01.381958 !!         VCPU0: Guru Meditation -79 (VERR_INVALID_STATE)
00:00:01.381961 !!
00:00:01.381965 !!
00:00:01.381965 !! {mappings, <NULL>}
00:00:01.381966 !!
00:00:01.381970
```

[Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/C9gQcKP4Rj/)'s the full log

Comment: have you fixed this?

Comment: @EkeymeMo https://askubuntu.com/a/1160520/558318

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just realized I got a Multipass instance running.  Didn't even realize it was running :face_palm:

All I had to do was stop that instance.

Comment: You just saved me, thanks! :)

Comment: Would you set it as accepted, as it solved it. It will be easier to find.